# How to check HTTP response code of a secured website with Nagios?

Tags: ssl, nagios, website, http-status-code

I want to create a nagios check of my secure website. All the check needs to do is login to the site with login details that I pass the script.

Does anyone know of a plugin or script that will allow me to do this?

I have tried using `check_http`, but I get success even if the website is redirected to an error page.

Comment: The `check_http` plugin supports the `-s string` option which enables you to look for certain string the HTTP response. If the page is printing a specific string on success, you can check it to distinguish it from error.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> I have tried using check_http but I get success even if the website is redirected to an error page

This can be solved with `check_http --expect`. Here is the documentation from [check_http --help](http://nagiosplugins.org/man/check_http):

> -e, --expect=STRING
>       Comma-delimited list of strings, at least one of them is expected in
>       the first (status) line of the server response (default: HTTP/1.)
>       If specified skips all other status line logic (ex: 3xx, 4xx, 5xx
>   processing)

The following example will return an 'OK' for a [200 OK](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) HTTP response code, but will give a critical error for a 302 redirect.

```
host % check_http --expect=200
HTTP CRITICAL - Invalid HTTP response received from host: HTTP/1.0 301 OK
```

For a secure website (over SSL), and authentication, also check out the check_http `--ssl` and the `--authorization` flags.

> -S, --ssl    Connect via SSL. Port
>   defaults to 443
>
> -a, --authorization=AUTH_PAIR
>       Username:password on sites with basic authentication

Or, perhaps you don't actually want to log into the system but just want to make sure that the page requires a username/password, because that username/password can become a security concern. In that case, try something like the following/ `401` is the HTTP response code for 'Unauthorized' or 'Authorization Required'-- the `401` is mandatory, the text string afterwards is optional and may say one of several different things, so I just tell Nagios to expect `401`.

```
check_http --expect="401"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create more complex checks (in the spirit of Behavior Driven Development/Monitoring) with [Cucumber-Nagios](http://auxesis.github.com/cucumber-nagios/).